# My smart phone no longer appears kin the run/debug configurations drop-down

Tags: android, android-studio

The first day my V60 thinQ smart phone worked fine with android studio.  The next day after working on my project for about a hour my smart phone no longer showed up in the run/debug configurations drop-down. I was not able to run the app on my device.

I went to trouble shoot device connection
When I clicked on Re-scan device my smart phone showed up.  Also in windows Explore my smart phone shows up,

Right before my device stop showing up a dialog came up asking me what i wanted to do after plugging in my smart phone. I forgot exactly what it said and what I clicked on.

Does any one know what is going on?????

Comment: When you run `adb devices`, what results do you get?

Comment: may be you need to enter in developer mode again by clicking build number 7 times then check allow debug option from developer options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, the popup that you saw right after plugging your device is asking if you trust your PC to connect over adb usb-debugging mode.

Sometimes, this happens to me. The way it works for me is: `going to Developer Options > USB Debugging Mode`. Then, i disable usb debugging then, re-enable it again and after that usually Android Studio detects it or, it shows the popup again. If you don't see the popup just unplug and re-plug your device once.

The popup should look sth like this with an RSA fingerprint of your computer:
[image: popup-image]

Now, you have to click: "Allow". And, android studio should detect your device.